# Ignore "Unknown option" errors in vimrc

Tags: vim

I tote the same .vimrc between machines that have both Vim 7.2 and 7.3 installed. The machines with Vim 7.2 complain about my 7.3-specific options every time I open a file:

```
Error detected while processing /home/spiffytech/.vimrc:
line   72:
E518: Unknown option: rnu
line   73:
E518: Unknown option: undofile
line   74:
E518: Unknown option: undodir=/tmp
line   75:
E518: Unknown option: cryptmethod=blowfish
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I make Vim ignore these errors and not prompt me to hit enter whenever I open files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap the new options in:

```
if version >= 703
  set rnu ...
endif
```

Check the help for `v:version` for more info on the version number to use:

```
                                        *v:version* *version-variable*
v:version       Version number of Vim: Major version number times 100 plus
                minor version number.  Version 5.0 is 500.  Version 5.1 (5.01)
                is 501.  Read-only.  "version" also works, for backwards
                compatibility.
                Use |has()| to check if a certain patch was included, e.g.: >
                        if has("patch123")
<               Note that patch numbers are specific to the version, thus both
                version 5.0 and 5.1 may have a patch 123, but these are
                completely different.
```

Comment: That works. Definitely be careful setting the version number- took a while for me to read thoroughly enough to see that it's *not* simply "version * 100"

Comment: Yeah, that can be tricky, but you get used with it. I'd rather describe it in a string concatenation sense, instead of doing math. Note that this is used in many other places. Perl, for example, uses a similar syntax with [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html). You have to `use 5.010;` to use features from perl `5.10`, which is not `5.1`. That's why they use it not in the decimal sense, otherwise you'd create some ambiguity.

Comment: It is better to test for the specific feature than version, since a specific version could be compiled without the feature you are looking for.

Comment: Much better to test for feature. Fedora 21's default vim is 7.4, but is compiled without folding which was added in 6.0.

Comment: Definitely should be checking for the required feature rather than assuming that a specific version number will be sufficient.

Answer (score 19):

It might be worth doing more fine-grained checking for actual supported features rather than versions.

E.g.:

```
if has('persistent_undo')
  set undofile
  set undodir=/tmp
endif

" Some options can only be checked with exists('+option'); I'm not sure why
if exists('+relativenumber')
  set rnu
endif

if has('cryptv')
  set cryptmethod=blowfish
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes an option is legitimate, but not available in the current environment.  For example:

```
$ vi
Error detected while processing /home/username/.vimrc:
line    9:
Unknown option: indentexpr=
```

To test whether an option exists or not, and avoid an error if not available:

```
if exists("&indentexpr")
  :set indentexpr=
endif
```

Comment: This does not fiddle around with version numbers.

Answer (score 5):

You can ignore any error with `silent! ...`, like `silent! set undofile`

Answer (score 3):

In you .vimrc, you can test against the Vim version you are executing.

See `help v:version`

```
if v:version >= 703
    "do something
    set rnu
    set undofile
    ...
endif
```

**703** corresponds to Vim 7.3 (which is not really intuitive...)

Answer (score 0):

I would say this question is not answered.  Consider a Session.vim created on computer A which has the later vim version.  In source control when another computer B tries to open the Session.vim the errors are triggered.  It makes no sense to have to manually wrap a version number for what should be an automated process. With this behaviour the new version would have to automatically wrap a new command in a version number when saving a session - something which 7.3 does not do.